# Accessing data from .XML file with Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, extract

I've got a **.XML** file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Comments</key>
<string></string>
<key>DataSummary</key>
<dict>
    <key>AreaCM2</key>
    <real>2.77</real>
    <key>Dev</key>
    <real>9.48</real>
</dict>
<key>DataValues</key>
<array>
    <real>81</real>
    <real>85</real>
</array>
<key>ROIPoints</key>
<array>
    <string>{65.7414, 58.2929}</string>
    <string>{65.7388, 58.4421}</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'd like to access `DataValues` and `ROIPoints` ***using MATLAB***.

I found quite a far fetched way of extracting `ROIPoints` which works like this:

```
DOMnode = xmlread(pathofxmlfile);
i       = DOMnode.getDocumentElement;
f       = char(i.getTextContent);
```

`f` is a string containing all the "text" contents:

`f = CommentsDataSummaryAreaCM22.77Dev9.48DataValues8185ROIPoints**{65.7414, 58.2929}{65.7388, 58.4421}`

Since `ROIPoints` are enclosed in curly brackets, I can manipulate the string in order to extract them.

Unfortunately, `DataValues` get horizontally concatenated (8185) and I cant extract them individually.

Any tips?

Comment: Looks like you can do a slightly more advanced version of what you have using xpath: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31382-using-xpath-from-matlab/content/html/xpath.html this way you can query to just get `ROIPoints` (i.e something like //key[ROIPoints]/array but I'm not 100% on the xpath syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out [xml_read](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools/content/xml_read.m) on matlab central. It will read your xml and output it as a struct (following your xml tree). It might be slow for larger XML's though.